# How to keep rpc open in Python

Tags: python, stream, protocol-buffers, grpc

I'm working on a gRPC client in Python that should receive notifications from a server written in c++. The issue I'm having is that when I call the rpc stream it closes instantly leading to me subscribing and unsubscribing to the notification stream and missing notifications when I'm unsubscribed. Is there a way to keep the rpc from closing in python?

the rpc has the format notification (stream notificationRequest) returns (stream notificationReply)

The code that continuously subscribes and unsubscribes looks like follows

```
request = server_pb2.NotificationRequest()
requests = [request]

while True:
    responses = stub.notification(iter(requests))
    for response in responses:
        print(response.node.id, int(response.id))
```

When only executing the rpc once the server log shows the rpc closing instantly after executing it.

```
responses = stub.notification(iter(requests))
```

What changes have to be made to the request to keep the rpc open indefinitely?

Comment: Can you post your server code? My hunch is your server is ending the stream once it runs out of data to send.

Comment: sorry for the late response, there is another client written in cpp that does keep the RPC open so the server doesn't seem to close the stream (I am not able to post the server code). The difference between the python and cpp code is that in cpp the stream has to be closed manually which in python it doesn't.